# Multi-colored Shadow Swift

Tags: ios, swift

In the iOS music app, I've noticed the shadow underneath album artwork changes based on the color of the artwork. This shadow can also be multi-colored based on how the color at the edge of the artwork changes.

Does anyone know how to recreate this effect programmatically?

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @Josh Homann for pointing me in the right direction, but the answer was actually much more complex.

1. The first (bottom) UIView in the hierarchy should have a plain white background and be pinned to the edges of the screen.
2. The next view should be a UIImageView with an alpha of 0.75.
3. Then you should add a UIVisualEffectView with the same dimensions as the first view.
4. Finally, add another UIImageView that is the **same size** as the first UIImageView.

Your IB hierarchy should look similar to this:

[image: IB Hierarchy]

The final result is this:

[image: Final Result]

Answer (score 0):

Its not a shadow its a [UIVisualEffectView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uivisualeffectview) with a blur.  Add a second image view under your image view with a larger size and add a blurring visualEffectView to it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to revive an old question, but this library nailed it: [ShadowImageView](https://github.com/olddonkey/ShadowImageView).

It uses `CIFilter` which gives you more control over the blur effect and better results.